# passing a variable length array to a function, should I use array length parameter or array end marker?

Tags: c

when I an designing a c function that needs to take a variable length array, how do I choose between:

1. adding another parameter to give the array length? and
2. terminating the array with a special marker (such as '\0')?
3. some other option?  what?

E.g.

```
void myfunc(int arr[], int arr_length) { ... }
...
int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
myfunc(myarr, 3);
```

or

```
void myfunc(int arr[]) { ... }
...
int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, '\0' };
myfunc(arr);
```

Comment: i prefer the former, so you dnt access out of bounds.

Comment: Passing the length works always. A sentinel is often a legitimate value some time later.

Comment: You know that `'\0'` is the same as `0`, right?

Comment: Depending on what your function does, you could also go for a printf-style variable-length argument setup.

Comment: Another vote for passing the array length - in addition to the reasons mentioned already, by knowing the length, you can tell up-front whether a particular index is within the array bounds, but with a sentinel, you must scan the entire array to find it before you can determine the validity of accessing a particular index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is to pass an array length, unless the array is a character array (i.e., a string); in that case, C will automatically null-terminate the string with 0x00.

You could use a null-terminator of your choosing to terminate the array. For example, if you have an array of signed ints but somehow you know that none of them will be negative, you could use -1 (or any negative number). The problem with using null-terminators is that you lose some possible values. Take, for example, a data type that's 4 bits long. If I define 0b1111 as the terminator, then the maximum value I can put in my array of this type is 0b1110. The reason strings are null terminated is that in ASCII, there are more numbers between 0 and 255 than there are characters we wanted to express, so using a null-terminator doesn't cost anything.

If you pass the array length, and are looping over all the values in the array, then you automatically have the max value to use in the for loop. Besides, in C, you almost always know the length of your array when you create it.

EDIT: And as far as passing the array end marker, it shouldn't be a problem for programs you run on your computer, but I would reconsider because different hardware implementations have different sizes of data types. If you have an array of 4 ints (16 bits) on your computer, your array starting at 0x1000 will end at 0x1008 (for example) on your computer but will end at 0x1004 on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `int arr_length` as a global variable. No need to pass it then.

Or

Pass the length as an argument. But never use a special character as an end marker. If you pass `'\0'` like `int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, '\0' };`. Then `arr[3]` will store the ASCII equivalent of `'\0'` (**0**) and which could very well be a part of a legitimate input.

Comment: what if there is a need to call this function multiple times, and may be some other function needs to access both the arrays simultaneously?